# creating site workflows with SharePoint designer 2013 but using SP 2010 platform doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I created a site workflow using sharepoint designer 2013 but used the sharepoint 2010 workflow platform has the SP 2013 workflow platform isn't available yet.

But when i published my workflow i can't see the workflow when i try to start it form the workflow page.
I get "The item has no workflow to start"

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: Is "Allow to start manually" checked? Please, place here the main page of WF.

Comment: Additionally, site workflow starts from site content page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a site workflow, It will be available under 
**Site Contents --> Site Workflows**. 
Did you try looking it there?

[image]

I have created a test site WF using 2010 WF template. After publishing, It becomes available under site workflows

[image]

Hope this helps !!

Comment: One more question can i schedule site workflow to run continuously?

Comment: One way of scheduling is set up a delay and use GoTo step to run the WF again.. Or else there is a paid tool available SP Store namely "Workflow scheduler"

Comment: Thanks DVG. To run this schedule workflow must the workflow be a Sharepoint 2013 workflow? I can't see GoTo step. Thanks in advance